# Method undefined for modules in rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

File structure:

```
../controllers
    /api
      /v1
        users_controller.rb
  some_controller.rb
```

Inside users_controller.rb

```
module Api
  module V1
    class UsersController < ApplicationController
      def create
        return false
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I can include Api in a controller and do Api::V1::UsersController.  However, when I try

Api::V1::UsersController.create

in any controller I get an error:

```
undefined method `create' for Api::V1::UsersController:Class
```

I've tried doing modules in lib, but the rails 4 autoloading was being weird so I tried doing it this way, but I don't know why my methods are undefined.  When I go into the console and puts Api::V1::UsersController.methods.sort, the :create method isn't there.  So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to declare the class name with the folder's names: `class Api::V1::UsersController < ApplicationController`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`create` is not a class method. It can't be called as `Class.method`.

You need an instance of this class to call it.

If you just want to try(though this is not the way controller work)

```
Api::V1::UsersController.new.create
```